# Open and write into file conditionally

Tags: rust

I'm doing and reduced sed replacement in rust where output file is optional.

Everything compiles Ok except that cargo build tells that maybe "file" variable can be uninitialized.

My code looks like this:

```
use std::env;
use std::fs;
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::BufReader;
use std::io::BufRead;
use std::io::prelude::*;

fn main() {

    const EMPTY_STRING :String = String::new();

    let count  :u8 = env::args().len() as u8;
    let mut args :[String; 4] = [EMPTY_STRING; 4];
    let subject: String;
    let input_filename: String;
    let output_filename: String;
    let mut file;
    let mut has_output_file :bool = false;

    if count < 3 {
        println!("USAGE: rs_sed s/regex/replacement/ input_file <output_file>");
        return;
    }

    for (index, arg) in env::args().enumerate() {
        if index < 4 {
            args[index] = arg;
        }
    }

    subject = args[1].clone();
    input_filename = args[2].clone();
    output_filename = args[3].clone();

    if output_filename != "" {
        has_output_file = true;
    }


    let _parts = subject.split("/");
    let parts = _parts.collect::<Vec<_>>();

    if parts[0] != "s" {
        println!("Unknown command");
        return;
    }

    let pattern = Regex::new(parts[1]).unwrap();
 
    let mut result :String;

    let input_file = fs::File::open(input_filename).unwrap();

    let reader = BufReader::new(input_file);

    if has_output_file {
        file = match File::create(output_filename) {
            Err(why) => panic!("File cannot be opened {}", why),
            Ok(file) => file, 
        };
    }

    for line in reader.lines() {
        result = pattern.replace_all(line.unwrap().as_str(), parts[2]).to_string();
        if has_output_file {
            match file.write_all(result.as_bytes()) {
                Err(why) => panic!("Data cannot be written {}", why),
                Ok(_) => continue,
            };
        } else {
            println!("{}", result);
        }
    }

    if has_output_file {
        file.flush();
    }
}
```

Cargo build result is

```
error[E0381]: used binding `file` is possibly-uninitialized
  --> src/main.rs:77:9
   |
18 |     let mut file;
   |         -------- binding declared here but left uninitialized
...
58 |         file = match File::create(output_filename) {
   |         ----
   |         |
   |         binding initialized here in some conditions
   |         binding initialized here in some conditions
...
77 |         file.flush();
   |         ^^^^ `file` used here but it is possibly-uninitialized

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0381`.
error: could not compile `rs_sed` (bin "rs_sed") due to previous error
```

I know the compiler is complaining about the "file" variable should be initialized but I don't know to handle a situation likes this because, in some cases, that variable is not needed to have an initial value.

How could I do this?

Comment: Get rid of `has_output_file` and change `file` to be an `Option`?

Answer (score 1):

As eggyal suggest, rather than have a boolean and some associated data set if the boolean is, which the compiler can't correlate with one another, it's more sensible to use [`Option`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html) which straight up encapsulates the entire concept: [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=6a040bc4633149161650a21b77fc3bfd)

```rust
let mut file = if !output_filename.is_empty() {
    File::create(output_filename)
        .unwrap_or_else(|e| panic!("File cannot be opened {e}"))
        .into()
} else {
    None
};
```

```rust
if let Some(file) = file.as_mut() {
    file.write_all(result.as_bytes())
        .unwrap_or_else(|e| panic!("Data cannot be written {e}"));
} else {
    println!("{}", result);
}
```

The setup code is also very procedural and complex (also not sure what the deal is with all the declarations at the top, that is *very* unusual). I would suggest [adding `itertools` to the dependencies](https://docs.rs/itertools/latest/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.collect_tuple) and writing something like:

```rust
let Some((_, subject, input_filename, output_filename)) =
    env::args().collect_tuple()
else {
    eprintln!("USAGE: rs_sed s/regex/replacement/ input_file <output_file>");
    return;
};

let Some((command, pattern, repl)) = subject.split("/").collect_tuple() else {
    eprintln!("Unknown command");
    return;
};
```